# 8-move checkmate with king

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

This is a pretty unusual chess game. Checkmate with the king on move 8. Based on the three moves provided, can you reconstruct the game?

> 5.Nd2
>   7... a6
>   8.Kd1#

Comment: Are we to assume that the moves shown in 5. and 8. are whites and the visible move in 7. is black?

Comment: @gabbo1092 Yes, that's correct. I tried to post an entire scoresheet with the unknown moves replaced with question marks, but the page wouldn't let me post it, sayng that it "doesn't conform to quality standards" :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one answer, but it doesn't seem to be completely unique

> 1. d4 Nc6
>  2. Bg5 Nxd4
>  3. Bf6 Nxe2
>  4. Kxe2 exf6
>  5. **Nd2** Ke7
>  6. Qe1 Nh6  Note: other moves are possible here 
>  7. Nc4 **a6** 
>  8. **Kd1#**